# Comparing int columns in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two int columns. OrgNum in the Org table and ServiceNum in the Service table. OrgNum has 1892 distinct rows. ServiceNum has 2362 distinct rows.

```
select distinct orgnum from org
where orgnum in (select distinct servicenum from services)
```

The above query returns 3 records.

```
select distinct orgnum from org
where orgnum not in (select distinct servicenum from services)
```

This query returns no records.

How is this possible because either OrgNum exists in ServiceNum or it doesn't. Both are not possible. Is there a different way to compare int's in SQL?

Comment: Please provide at least a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (in this particular case, some sample data would be helpful). Is there any chance there's a `NULL` value in `services`.`servicenum`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`not in` has strange behavior when the subquery returns *any* `null` values.  In this case, no rows are returned.

For this reason, I recommend that you always use `not exists`:

```
select distinct o.orgnum
from org o
where not exists (select 1 from services s where o.orgnum = s.servicenum);
```

This behavior is explainable.  In SQL, `null` generally has the semantics of "unkonwn" rather than "missing".  So:

```
1 in (2, 3)            -- returns false (you know it is not there)
1 in (null, 2, 3)      -- returns null (could be there or not).  BUT `null` is treated like false in where
1 not in (2, 3)        -- returns true
1 not in (null, 2, 3)  -- returns null.  But this is treated as false.
```